# Drag and Drop producing undesirable results

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, drag-and-drop

I've been experiencing a bug in my program that I can't seem to figure out. Basically when my game starts I have a loop that iterates over all of the pieces that will be dragged and dropped. However, When I am actually testing it, periodically (and it seems like the bug is dependent on which element I try to drag first, and then effects the ones after) I will go to drag an item, and when I try to drop it, the drop event will not occur BUT if I go to the top-left elements of the table, and drag each one, from left to right, eventually all the pieces are able to be dragged and dropped but only in a specific order. I have been trying to work this out but have run out of ideas. Here is a live demo of the problem, it begins when I select the first pentagon, this does not happen on every game played...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-izy_tuxmdg

The loop I am using is like this, it's part of an object that I call when the program starts:

```
enablePieces:    function() {
                         for(var i = 0; i < this.dragPieces.length; i++) {
                             this.dragPieces[i].ondragstart = this.dragStart;
                             this.targetPieces[i].ondragover = this.allowDrop;
                             this.targetPieces[i].ondrop = this.doDrop;
                      };

},
```

When I call the method it's like this:

```
Perfection.start = function() {
    newGame();
    *Perfection.view.enablePieces();*
    Perfection.controls.startButton.onclick = beginGame;
    Perfection.controls.newButton.onclick = newGame;
};
```

I should mention as well that when I grab the elements from the DOM it's like this:

```
dragPieces    :   document.querySelectorAll(".piecetray td img"),
targetPieces  :   document.querySelectorAll(".gametray td img"),
```

and when I type Perfection.view.dragPieces into the console I get:

```
Perfection.view.dragPieces
NodeList 
[ <img>, <img>, <img>, <img>, <img>, <img>, <img>, <img>, <img>, <img>, 26 more… ]
```

But if I create an array `var dragArray = [ ];` and then push all the elements in the "NodeList" into this array and then type the array into the console, I get:

```
dragArray
Array [ <img>, <img>, <img>, <img>, <img>, <img>, <img>, <img>, <img>, <img>, 26 more… ]
```

I didn't think there was any difference between the two, but now I am questioning myself, It seems when using the array I created it happens less, but that could just be a lack of testing one less than the other, can anyone tell me why this is happening?

The drag and drop functions are also posted here:

```
dragStart   :   function(event) {
                    var piece = event.currentTarget;
                    piece.classList.add("selected"); 
                },
allowDrop   :   function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                },
doDrop      :   function(event) {
                    var bestTime = 0;
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var currentPiece = document.querySelector(".selected");
                    var targetPiece = event.currentTarget;
                    var targetParent = targetPiece.parentElement;
                    if (getName(currentPiece) === getName(targetPiece)) { 
                        targetParent.appendChild(currentPiece);
                        currentPiece.classList.remove("selected");
                        currentPiece.classList.add("matched");
                        matchedCount++;
                    };
                    if ((matchedCount === 36) && (Perfection.timeLeft !== 0)) 
                        if(Perfection.timeLeft > bestTime) {
                            Perfection.view.updateScore("Best time " + timer.innerHTML);
                            bestTime = Perfection.timeLeft;
                            clearInterval(Perfection.timer);
                    };
```

Comment: Any live demo for this? Would help to actually see the problem in this case.

Comment: @zozo here is a live demo, watch as the problem begins when I attempt to drop the first pentagon. You can see once I get to the top left corner of the table and move sequentially it works. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-izy_tuxmdg

Comment: I was hoping for an online link to be able to debug (the code has no obvious error - at least I don't see one) :). Given the fact that it happens random I'm thinking that maybe an event missfire (this is only a guess). Could you add some logs on dragStart and doDrop? this way you isolate the problem to only one function. Also try keeping a console open for errors. Unfortunately can't help you more with current data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the line:

currentPiece.classList.remove("selected");

Because it was placed inside the condition, the class was only being removed if it was a match, but it should have been removed regardless, on every drop event.